# fastest way to query database in java

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I have a MSSQL Database, and I have a stored procedure for any possible query, most of them just return a row of data with 3 columns or just execute an INSERT 
How in java to **connect to the DB** and **execute a stored procedure**, and retrieve some data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A connection pool like [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) makes a big difference. The connection time can be save this way.

[Prepared statements](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) can help the database to skip query parsing. The parsed statements will be cached.

[Batch updates](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch%28%29) help when you're executing a statement repeatedly.

Setting the right [fetch size](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) is another optimization for queries.

Comment: I'm going to get just a row of data, always, this means I should set a fetch size of 1 ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the MSSQL JDBC Driver to create a connection to the database
2. In jdbc, you need to create a CallableStatement to execute the procedure. It's like this:

.

```
CallableStatement callable = null;
try {
   String sqlCommand = "{call yourProcNameHere (?, ? /* ... */)}";
   callable = conn.prepareCall(sqlCommand);
   // ...
}
catch (SQLException e) {
   // ...
}
finally {
   / ...
}
```

Comment: The jTDS driver can be used to connect to MSSQL and Sybase.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

By reading and working through a [JDBC Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).